# 描画範囲を制限したい

Tags: c#, unity3d

ゲームでの描画範囲を高さで制限したいです。

例えば、高さ10メートルのオブジェクトが存在し、描画範囲が高さ8メートルならオブジェクトの上2メートル部分は非表示になる。
尚且つカメラで上から見たときに、そのオブジェクトの断面が見える。というものを作りたいのですが実装方法が分かりません。

よろしくお願いします。

以上

Comment: この描画範囲が制限されるものは、特定のオブジェクトのみが制限される形になるのでしょうか。それとも描画される全てのものが制限されるのでしょうか。
オブジェクトの断面が見えるということは、オブジェクトが半透明になるということを指していますでしょうか。

Comment: 言葉足らずで申し訳ありません。
「描画される全てのものを制限したい」です。
オブジェクトを半透明にするといった意図はありません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

シェーダーを使った描画範囲を制限する方法を提示します。
　描画される全てのものを制限するとなると、適応するのは難しいかも知れませんが、方法のひとつとして参考にしてみてください。
　
　ClipHeight.shader

```
Shader "Test/ClipHeight"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D)    = "white" {}
        _Height("Clip Height", float)           = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "RenderType"    = "Opaque"
        }

        Cull Off

    CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert

        struct Input
        {
            float2  uv_MainTex;
            float3  worldPos;
        };

        uniform sampler2D   _MainTex;
        uniform float       _Height;

        void surf( Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput OUT )
        {
            clip(-IN.worldPos.y + _Height);
            OUT.Albedo  = tex2D( _MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex ).rgb;
        }

    ENDCG

    }
}
```

ClipHeight.shaderは_Heightに指定した数値未満の部分を描画しないシェーダーです。
　そしてこのClipHeight.shaderを制御するのが以下のClipHeightコンポーネントです。
　
　ClipHeight.cs

```
public class ClipHeight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Height
    {
        set
        {
            m_material.SetFloat( "_Height", value );
        }
    }

    private Material    m_material;

    void Awake()
    {
        var render          = GetComponent< Renderer >();
        m_material          = render.material;

        // 強制的に、高さでクリップされるシェーダーに切り替える
        m_material.shader   = Shader.Find( "Test/ClipHeight" );        
    }
}
```

そして以下のClipHeightManagerコンポーネントがHierarchy上に存在するすべてのRnedererコンポーネントを持つGameObjectにClipHeightコンポーネントを追加するコンポーネントです。
　Heightプロパティが描画を制限する高さです。

```
public class ClipHeightManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float   m_height;

    private List<ClipHeight> m_cliptList = new List<ClipHeight>();

    public float Height
    {
        get
        {
            return m_height;
        }
        set
        {
            m_height    = value;
            foreach( var clip in m_cliptList )
            {
                clip.Height = m_height;
            }
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        // 現在Hierarchy上に存在する全てのRendererのマテリアルを専用シェーダに変更。

        var renderList  = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType< Renderer >();
        foreach( var render in renderList )
        {
            var clip    = render.gameObject.AddComponent< ClipHeight >();
            m_cliptList.Add( clip );
        }

        Height  = m_height;
    }
}
```

Heightプロパティを増減することで、以下のように描画範囲を制限できます。
　
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　
　ただこの方法では、描画する全てのオブジェクトのマテリアルのシェーダを専用のものにする必要があるため、汎用的に使うのは難しいかもしれません。